# Outlet box between shallow and standard?

Tags: receptacle, junction-box

Is there an outlet box that's shallower than a standard, but not as shallow as a "shallow"?

I need a box that's smaller than a standard, but don't need one that's SO shallow. Hoping there's an in between, but can't find one.

Comment: Might help if you defined what depths you mean by "standard" and "shallow." The boxes I use the most come 1-1/2" and 2-1/8" deep. Other boxes have other common (or standard) sizes.

Comment: Most manufacturers (and retailers) offer a range of volumes (box depths). The presumption is flawed.

Answer (score 4):

Shallow box with an extender ring? Or double gang metal box with a single gang mud ring if you need more volume could work. You can mount either box set back from the face of the drywall